# Add diffrenet href to some nodes in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I set href for some nodes and it works fine but the other nodes opening blank page Is it possible make them without href and don´t open blank page?

I used this to make href  :

```
cy.nodes('[id = "start"]').data('href', 'https://js.cytoscape.org/');

cy.on('tap', 'node', function() {
  try {
    window.open(this.data('href'));
  } catch (e) {
    window.location.href = this.data('href');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, listen for events that come from `node[href]`, this means nodes that have `href` within their data set.

```js
cy.on('tap', 'node[href]', function() {})
```

I'm not totally sure about this, but it should work. 
If not, just add

```js
if (!this.data('href')) return;
```

As the first line in your handler.

Comment: Hi Ravenous, how can I check if the href is null by using this cy.on('tap', 'node[href]', function() {})

Comment: Based on https://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/data, try `node[?href]`, `href` needs to be a "truthy" value to be considered, so `null` values should be discarded. If not, just add the check I mentioned inside the handler.